# Numpy.eig() function getting different results on Google colab with the same code

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

I'm using the NumPy. eig () function to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors from a matrix. However, when I run the same code below, it gives me a different result on google colab than jupyter.

```
M = np.array([[3/2, -1],[-1/2, 1/2]])
vals, vecs = np.linalg.eig(M)
vecs
```

on Google colab, I have the result：

```
array([[ 0.9390708 ,  0.59069049],
       [-0.34372377,  0.80689822]])
```

However, on jupyter it gives me something like

```
[[ 2.732,  1.],[-1., 1.366]]
```

I believe the later one should be correct, but it really confused me, why are they giving me different answers? And why google colab's calculation is wrong?
Thank you so much for your help and explanation in advance!

Comment: The former (one on colab) is correct. Take note of your python/numpy versions and try update python and numpy. Sometimes th versions would have issues.

Comment: Both are eigenvectors of M, but the vectors you get on Jupyter are not normalized. If you divide each column by its magnitude you get the same results. As @onyambu said, you should check that the versions of python and numpy match on both platforms.